# How many file format supported iOS to send in POST request and maximum Size of File Supported

Tags: ios, iphone

Hello I am working on iOS application in which I want to know about how many file format supported by iOS to send in POST request and also want to know about maximum file size supported any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what file do you need to upload in the first place?

Comment: Like documents,Images,Videos,exe,ipa,zip,rar any type of files

Comment: Not sure about the context here - in general, you should be able to send *any* type of data in a POST request